How to query OAuth2 permission grants for service principals in Entra ID using Microsoft Graph Powershell?
When I query service principals of application type with both delegated and application permissions for MS Graph, the OAuth2 permission grants (Oauth2PermissionGrants) are always returned as $null.
$servicePrincipal = Get-MgServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalId c3c1919a-eb0e-4664-96c7-3a4112345678

How can I return the OAuth2 permission grants for service principals?
Note: The AzureAD module doesn't work on arm64-based Mac.

Try with Invoke-MgGraphRequest GET v1.0/servicePrincipals/c3c1919a-eb0e-4664-96c7-3a4112345678/oauth2PermissionGrants

@SantiagoSquarzon Thank you! That works, however, the result doesn't list the resource that defines the scope. For MS Graph scopes, the principalId is null, while the resource ID identity the permission grant itself. Do you know why this works, while Get-MgServicePrincipal doesn't? How do I get the resource in the result?

@SantiagoSquarzon Also, would you mind comment on this? https://serverfault.com/questions/1164279/how-to-tag-entra-id-resources-like-users-groups-etc-so-that-the-tags-cant

I'm sorry I dont use the cmdlets from that module except for Invoke-MgGraphRequest for direct API queries. The rest of the cmdlets are pure trash. No idea why Get-MgServicePrincipal doesn't return this, doesn't surprise me either.

Invoke-MgGraphRequest is making an http request while Get-MgServicePrincipal is logging into the remote machine to get data.  Invoke-MgGraphRequest will use the user/role to get access to the data.  Invoke-MgGraphRequest may require an Admin to get access to other users account.

@jdweng What do you mean by “logging into the remote machine”? I’m targeting Entra ID

When you are targeting a remote machine there is a login using you credentials that is done automatically.

@jdweng But I'm not targeting a remote machine in case of Entra ID? Doesn't your comment only apply to Active Directory?

Are you running as an Admin?  Make sure you run your PS cmdlet by right click the PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Shuzheng: just ignore whatever the user above says. 99/100 comments are pure bs. Can you clarify on what you mean by "the result doesn't list the resource that defines the scope" ? I thought the resource defining the scope is what you'd see on the resourceId property from the response of the API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list-oauth2permissiongrants?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response-1

Sorry, you're right. resourceId is indeed the ID of the resource that defines the scope. It's the object ID of the service principal

@SantiagoSquarzon Did you have a chance to comment on my question regarding immutable tagging of Entra ID objects, like applications, groups, etc. I don't want owners to be able to change or remove tags

For sample, I granted few delegated and application API permissions to the Microsoft Entra ID application:

To fetch the delegated API permissions, use the below command:
Get-MgServicePrincipalOauth2PermissionGrant -ServicePrincipalId ServicePrincipalId


To fetch the application type API permissions, use the below command:
 Get-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId ServicePrincipalId



Thank you @Rukmini. How would you query the app role's value for an app role ID, like Application.Read.All?

Sure please post a new question with details will help you there

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78918574/how-to-get-the-app-roles-value-given-an-app-role-id-in-entra-id-using-microsoft

Okay sure will check and update
