How to get the app role's value given an app role ID in Entra ID using Microsoft Graph Powershell?
After getting the app role assignments to a service principal:
Get-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId ServicePrincipalId

I want to get the value for each app role. The response includes an app role ID and a resource ID for each assigned app role.
I can get the app roles for an application as follows, but then I would first need to map the service principal's object ID (resource ID) to the object ID of the associated application:
(Get-MgApplication -ApplicationId ApplicationId).AppRoles

Is there an easier way?

To fetch the app role's value given an app role ID in Entra ID using Microsoft Graph PowerShell, make use of below script:
I granted few  application API permissions  to the Microsoft Entra ID application:

$ServicePrincipalId = "ServicePrincipalObjectID"

$AppRoleAssignments = Get-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId $ServicePrincipalId

$AssignedRoles = @()
foreach ($Assignment in $AppRoleAssignments) {
    $ResourceId = $Assignment.ResourceId
    $AppRoleId = $Assignment.AppRoleId

    $ServicePrincipal = Get-MgServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalId $ResourceId

    $AppRole = $ServicePrincipal.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.Id -eq $AppRoleId }

    if ($AppRole) {
        $AssignedRoles += [PSCustomObject]@{
            'App Role ID'                    = $AppRole.Id
            'App Role Display Name'          = $AppRole.DisplayName
            'App Role Value'                 = $AppRole.Value
        }
    }
}

$AssignedRoles | Format-Table -AutoSize



Thank you! Why do app roles both live on the application and the associated service principal? In the portal, app roles are configured on the application, not the service principal (there you assign users/groups to app roles)

When you grant admin consent to app roles it will be reflected in permissions blad of service principal too

@Shuzheng Did the above script worked for you?

Yes, added app roles will be reflected in the permissions blade of the service principal. But the app roles are not defined on the service principal, they are defined on the application in the app roles blade

Yes I agree and you cannot define roles in Service principal.  Service principal is in the instance of application and hence the permissions will be reflected in Service Principal permissions blade too

Service Principals don't define their own roles but instead reflect the roles defined by the application to which they are associated. App Roles are defined on the application, and these roles are then made available through the service principal in the tenant where the application is used.

Thank you. This is not true: these roles are reflected in the service principal's permissions. The application may define 100 app roles, but the app roles showing up in the service principal's permissions are only those assigned to it

Haha, yes. I want to list all directory extension definitions within a tenant using Get-MgDirectoryObjectAvailableExtension. However, it only returns a few (not those created on applications within my tenant). Reading those directory extension attributes directly of an application using Get-MgApplicationExtensionProperty -ApplicationId ApplicationId yields extension attributes not returned by Get-MgDirectoryObjectAvailableExtension. Do you have any idea?

Please post a new question with details I will help you there and paste the link here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78919334/how-to-list-all-directory-extension-definitions-within-an-entra-id-tenant

I have posted a new question. Thanks for helping @Rukmini

Sure will check and update
