How to list all directory extension definitions within an Entra ID tenant?
How to list all directory extension definitions within an Entra ID tenant.
Get-MgDirectoryObjectAvailableExtension returns only a few directory extension definitions originating from multi-tenant applications:

Return all directory extension definitions that have been registered
in a directory, including through multi-tenant apps.

In particular, directory extension definitions created on an application in the tenant aren't returned. They are returned by Get-MgApplicationExtensionProperty -ApplicationId ApplicationId, which requires an application ID.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.directoryobjects/get-mgdirectoryobjectavailableextensionproperty?view=graph-powershell-1.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.applications/get-mgapplicationextensionproperty?view=graph-powershell-1.0


This endpoint might be the one you're looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schemaextension-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell

@SantiagoSquarzon Schema extensions and directory extensions are not the same thing

To list all directory extension definitions within a Microsoft Entra ID tenant, make use of below PowerShell script as a workaround:
# Retrieve all applications in the tenant
$applications = Get-MgApplication
$allExtensions = @()

# Loop through each application to get its extension properties
foreach ($app in $applications) {
    $extensions = Get-MgApplicationExtensionProperty -ApplicationId $app.Id
    $allExtensions += $extensions
}

# Retrieve available extension properties for directory objects
$directoryExtensions = Get-MgDirectoryObjectAvailableExtensionProperty

# Combine both results
$allExtensions += $directoryExtensions
$allExtensions



There is no direct command to fetch both directory and all application extension properties.


Thank you. Why doesn’t Get-MgDirectoryObjectAvailableExtension work? Directory extensions can’t be defined on the directory, but only on applications. Can you elaborate?

I guess its by default that it returns all directory extension definitions that have been registered in a directory

but AFAIK directory extension definitions can only be defined on an application. Have you ever encountered directory extension definitions registered on a directory?

Yes directory extension definitions can only be defined on an application.

Please, see the screenshot I added to my question. Get-MgDirectoryObjectAvailableExtension should return all directory extensions, but it doesn't. The ones defined on the application aren't returned. Is this a bug?

Your script need Get-MgApplication -All on the first line, otherwise it only returns 100 applications

Yeah I do not have more than 100 applications so missed that. You can include -All flag

I dont feel its a bug the commands are built for different scenarios

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Yes, thank you. Thus, I had hoped you could explain the difference between application- and directory extensions

Sure will research and get back to you

Found something? :)

Will update soon:)

Thank you looking forward to it

You can call Get-MgApplication and expand extensionProperties
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Applications

Get-MgApplication -All -ExpandProperty "extensionProperties" -Property "id,appId" 


Thank you. You don't return the set of attributes and only select other properties :)
